# Query num times users attended same party

Tags: mysql

I have the schemas below

```
Friends Table
----------
user1_id
user2_id

Party
-----
user_id
party_id
```

And I'm trying to find the num of parties user1 and user2 both attended. So for example

```
Friends Table 
----------
user1 | user 2
1       2     ( user 1 is connected to user 2)
1       4     ( user 1 is connected to user 4)
2       3
2       4

Party
--------
userid | partyid
1        1       (user 1 joined party 1)
2        1       ( user 2 also joined party 1)
1        2
2        2
1        3
2        3
4        3
```

Would return results that user 1 and user 2 both attended 3 of the same parties, user 2 and 4 joined 1 party together, and user 1 and 4 also joined 1 party together

I was thinking of grabbing all parties user1 attended, then grab all parties user2 attended and using a UNION on party_id, but is there a way to do that in one query for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify what User connected means?

Ignoring user connected, you could try the following

```
select P1.userId, P2.userId, count(*)
from Party as P1, Party as P2
where P1.partyId = P2.partyId and P1.userId < P2.userId
group by P1.userId, P2.userId
```

This would give you the count of the number of parties that each user pair of users went to together.

Comment: wow ;( I spent hours trying to think of it and you thought of it in 2 sec. Thank you :)